# Get all data from sql php

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

I want to get all locations in table travel_location in mysql. This is my code

```
$select = $this->_db_table->select()->from(travel_location, array('*'));

    $result = $this->_db_table->fetchAll($select);


    if(count($result) == 0) {
        throw new Exception('not found',404);
    }

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $user_object = new Api_Model_User($row1);

        $count = 1;

        $json = array($json[$count] = array(
        'travel_location_id' => $user_object->travel_location_id,
        'city_id' => $user_object->city_id,
        'user_id' => $user_object->user_id,
        'location_name' => $user_object->location_name,
        'description' => $user_object->description,
        'longitude' => $user_object->longitude,
        'latitude' => $user_object->latitude,
        'created_time' => $user_object->created_time,
        'updated_time' => $user_object->updated_time));

        $count++;
    }
```

It doesn't work. I print $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result) and it returns false, so I think it's wrong because of this line. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried print_r($result)? fetchAll() should return all of the rows, and you shouldn't need mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: thanks but i have tried and it's just return some infomations of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `fetchAll` from Zend_Db_Table you get a [Zend_Db_Table_Rowset](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html) as result.

Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // $row should be a Zend_Db_Table_Row object
    // you can cast to array
    $rowArray = $row->toArray();
    $user_object = new Api_Model_User($rowArray);
}
```

Read more about [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.fetch-all.usage) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html)